# Trying to deploy bitbucket in marathon/mesos

Tags: bitbucket, mesos, bitbucket-server, marathon, mesosphere

I am trying to deploy Bitbucket in maratahon, but the when I scale the application, it is bouncing and spanning into multiple services.
I don't know why can you help any one how to handle.

**marathon_bitbucket.json**

```
 {
     "id": "/test/bitbucket",
  "cmd": "sh /tmp/app/atlassian-bitbucket-4.8.3/start-bitbucket.sh",
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 512,
  "disk": 1,
  "instances": 0,
  "container": null,
  "constraints": [
    [
      "hostname",
      "LIKE",
      "(lltws0gbeot.sdi.corp.bankofamerica.com)"
    ]
  ],
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 0,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": null,
      "labels": null
    }
  ],
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 60,
      "intervalSeconds": 60,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "delaySeconds": 15,
      "protocol": "COMMAND",
      "timeoutSeconds": 20,
      "command": {
        "value":"ps -ef | grep \"bitbucket\" | grep -v grep"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can any one please help how to solve the bouncing issue

Comment: Your `hostname` value looks like it refers to specific internal URL's within your company. I'd suggest editing that out and replacing it with something generic that doesn't identify your company at all.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a container image (null is not a valid image name). Did you mean to specify this?

container: "atlassian/bitbucket-server:latest"